# Binding multiple widgets to the same handler GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

I have multiple button that will proceed the same process when I click that..
Is there any idea to realize it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the same callback function. The first argument (in C, at least) will tell you which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the site for Gtk# I found this example showing how to bind a signal to a button: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T:Gtk.Button#

```
btn.Clicked += new EventHandler (btn_click);
btn2.Clicked += new EventHandler (btn_click);
```

I would assume that doing the same thing for multiple buttons would allow you to bind the clicked signal for all of them to the same process.

Now in order to tell which button it was that triggered the event you can look at the object passed to the callback function:

```
static void Window_Delete (object obj, DeleteEventArgs args)
```

In this case obj. Let me know if this works, I'm curious! I do not have Gtk# installed.

For Gtk+:

Using the g_signal_connect function simply use the same function. 
g_signal_connect(ptr_to_widget, "signal", G_CALLBACK(function), NULL)

If you want to use the same function and need to pass data to it you need to use a pointer to the data you would need to pass:
g_signal_connect(ptr_to_widget, "signal", G_CALLBACK(function), ptr_to_data)

There is no problem with connecting more than one widget to the same function.

Comment: Well, I need a method to capture the name property of the button that triggered the event. Looking for a method like "GetName" or something else, but not found yet. Do I need an assembly?

Comment: Looks like buttons do not have a name property, do you mean the label property?
http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.Button%2fP

Comment: Dude, I just found the solution..
using `Button clickedButton = sender as Button; if(clickedButton.Name == "Button1" { ... }`